# How do ``orthogonal basis'' of a Lie algebra behave under different representations

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Given a Lie algebra $g$, suppose that one can find a basis $(e_i)$ of $g$, such that under a certain irreducible representation,

$Tr (e_i^* e_j) =  C \delta_{ij}$,

where $e_i$, $e_j$ are understood as matrices, and $C$ is a constant.  Then a physics book says that if the above is true for one irreducible representation of $g$,  then it is true for all irreducible representations of $g$ for this basis, except that the constant $C$ depends on the particular representation.

I suppose this constant $C$ should be an important quantity for a Lie algebra representation then  -  does it have a name?

Comment: I think up to scale, for a simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, this should be the Casimir eigenvalue: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_element#Eigenvalues

Comment: $e_i^*$ means matrix transpose? And do you have a few examples for such $C$ for certain representations?